# Python ImportError: cannot import name datafunc [PyML]

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, pyml

I have installed [PyML](http://pyml.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html) package in order to use some machine learning algorithms, and according to the tutorial, my installation is successful.

I try to run a python script which includes the following line to import modules from PyML

> from PyML import datafunc,svm,assess,modelSelection,ker

However I get the error message above saying

> File `<stdin>`, line 1, in `<module>` ImportError: cannot import name
>   datafunc

cannot import name datafunc`. From terminal I check every module by saying

> from PyML import datafunc, 
>   from PyML import svm, 
>   from PyML import ker

I only get error message for `datafunc`. The PyML library is under the `site-packages` folder of Python 2.7.

I check this question here [Python error: ImportError: cannot import name Akismet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351919/python-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-akismet), but I could't see how it will help my problem.

Do you have any idea why Python imports some modules but does not import this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PyML-0.7.13.3, the `datafunc` module exists in `PyML/containers` directory.
So it seems that you can import the module as follows:

```
from PyML.containers import datafunc
```

Howerver, it raises an error beacuse the `datafunc` module uses
undefined classes `BaseVectorDataSet` and `SparseDataSet`.

Thus you need to modify the source of PyML 
in order to use `datafunc` module.
First, prepend the following two lines to `PyML/containers/datafunc.py`
and re-install the PyML library.

```
from PyML.containers.baseDatasets import BaseVectorDataSet
from PyML.containers.vectorDatasets import SparseDataSet
```

Then you can import the modules as follows:

```
from PyML import svm, modelSelection, ker
from from PyML.containers import datafunc
from from PyML.evaluators import assess
```

BTW, I recommend that you use more documented and tested machine learning library, such as [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/).

Comment: I actually try to run the source code of a research article, so I had to install PyML because they did so. Your method worked very well, thank you! However, this time I get this error message saying  `data = datafunc.KernelData(sys.argv[3])
AttributeError: module object has no attribute KernelData `. Any chance you have an idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `from PyML.containers import KernelData`

Comment: hmm, but it didn't solve the problem, because there is no `KernelData` in containers, but `kernelData`. Besides importing `kernelData` also didn't work :( Thanks anyway!