# How can i import PyML in colab?

Tags: python, import, google-colaboratory, pdfminer, pyml

i am trying to import PyML in colab and it tell me **" No module named 'PyML' "** i need to import it to use datafunc and.
I check this question [Python ImportError: cannot import name datafunc [PyML]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532860/python-importerror-cannot-import-name-datafunc-pyml)
, but it depend on import PyML.
can any one help me to solve this or tell me onther way to do what datafunc do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is:

1. clone the github:
    `!git clone https://github.com/gf712/PyML.git`

verify that you have respective folder now.

```
import os
os.listdir()
```

output will be like :

```
['.config', 'PyML', 'sample_data']
```

go to 'PyML'

```
cd PyML/
```

and then run the setup:

```
!python setup.py install
```

after all successful steps, `import PyML` will work.

Comment: Your solution worked very well, thank you very much!
but when i use PyML.containers it tell me " No module named 'PyML.containers' " how i can deal with it if you have an idea

Comment: are you planning to load the dataset? because I don't see the container in their GitHub(not sure  I overlooked it)

Comment: i need to "import data_func" in colab and in the and in the the above solution in the link i mentioned he said we use "from PyML.containers import datafunc"